# AirTable and VoIP Integration

Tags: voip, airtable

I run a local repair business which gets calls from multiple lead generating numbers. When our dispatchers answer the calls, they fill out an AirTable form w/ all the customers info. They are supposed to record what number the call was taken so we can track leads. Unfortunately, our VoIP doesn't show this in caller ID, so we have to rely on a very unreliable whisper message before they answer. Thus, to get reliable data, we need to match records ex post facto.

We want to switch to a new VoIP. I was hoping to find one that is or can be integrated w/ AirTable, so as soon as they answer the form already includes the number called  (and the customer's number).

Does this exist?